# Fetching data from Google analytics GA4 api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

This has probably something to do with recent migration to GA4, but for some reason my previous code stopped working and now I have problems with fetching basic data.

I think now I need to use different library, this is what I have so far but it crashes

- warning: undefining the allocator of T_DATA class GRPC::Core::MetadataArray
  objc[4318]: +[__NSTimeZone initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
  objc[4318]: +[__NSTimeZone initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead.*

```
require 'google/analytics/data/v1beta'

client = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = "config/google-api.json"
end


hash = {"property": "properties/XXXXXXXXXX", "dimensions":[{"name":"date"}],"metrics":[{"name":"activeUsers"}],"date_ranges":[{"start_date":"2023-10-01","end_date":"2023-10-10"}]}

request = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::RunReportRequest.new hash

response = client.run_report request
```

Thanks in advance.